# dealing with meaningless inconsistent data

Tags: machine-learning, data-mining, missing-data, data-preprocessing

Am trying to develop a predictive model, in the data set instances have an attribute `subject` with 40 possible values such as `{history, chemistry, c.r.e, economics, physics, biology, health science,...}` however, some values for `subject` appear as just `{a, f, c,...}` which does not necessarily predict the possible valid `subject` value. For example a subject recorded as `'c'` can be `'chemistry'` or `'c.r.e'`. Additionally there is an attribute `grades` corresponding to the subject per instance recorded with 7 possible values `{A, B, C, D, E, F, O}`. However none of the values for grades is missing unless the corresponding subject is also a missing value. Can i delete such values `({a, f, c,..} in place of valid subject value)` and deal with missing values instead?

Thank you

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. What else is there to do?

Comment: @Patrick Coulombe it is supposed to be a predictive model, however i need to document the analysis and data cleaning stages

Comment: Would you do so if, for example, there was one data entry person who used 'a' for 'art', 'f' for 'forensics', and 'c' for 'classics'?

Comment: @Matthew Drury it does not appear to be so, because it is extracted from a database of an organisation and from what i understand, it can only be an error as grades are represented as {A, B, C, D, E, F, O} but interestingly, a subject recorded as 'f' does not have a corresponding grade as 'F'

Comment: This would be good content for your question.  The meta point I'm making is that dealing with missing values is extremely contingent upon a good understanding of the process that generated the missings.  Please share the totality of you understanding of that process with us!

Comment: I slipped and used "missing" somewhat inappropriately above, I should have said "missing, confusing, or invalid data".

Comment: @Matthew Drury I have done some editing, i hope that shades more light

Comment: Clearly identify your questions in the post. Do you need help cleaning up the data? Are you unsure how to deal with missing data?

Comment: @FrankH. well, the data is not missing, but rather the cleaning. How do I deal with such inconsistent data, if it cannot be explained?

Comment: Probably worthwhile to spend more time figuring out why certain errors are occurring, and then forging a path to clean the data.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question about removing data and replacing - absolutely not. Unfortunately, you'll want to clean your data. In terms of cleaning your data, it may be good to go back to the source and make sure things are accurate. If you know c.r.e is equivalent to chemistry, then replace all c.r.e with chemistry. However that's only if you are 100% sure. If you are not certain, then you might be seriously undermining any analysis you do. Check with the original source to get clarification.

If you must, I would change those inconsistencies to missing values but it seems as though you have a lot of them and that they may not be missing at random. If that is the case, then any missing data analysis you do might be a poor representation of what is actually occurring.

My advice: before taking statistical steps, try a practical approach to clean your data.